# HashMap<Class<?>, List<Class<?>>> : specify that the lists' classes extend the keys'

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

One of my class need to store classes according to their superclasses. To that end, I'm using a HashMap, where keys are the superclasses, and values a list of their extended classes. So it looks like that :

```
HashMap<Class<?>, List<Class<?>>>
```

I'd like to know if there was a notation allowing me to be more precise, something like :

```
HashMap<Class<T>, List<Class<? extends T>>>
```

I've tried that and, of course, it doesn't work : T cannot be resolved. Is there a syntax that would allow me to do that ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with accessor methods.

```
// only accessed by methods which check the keys and values are the right type.
final Map<Class, List<Class>> map = new LinkedHashMap<Class, List<Class>>();

public <T, S extends T> void add(Class<T> key, Class<S> value) {
    List<Class> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null)
        map.put(key, list = new ArrayList<Class>());
    list.add(value);
}

public <T, S extends T> List<Class<S>>get(Class<T> key) {
    return (List<Class<S>>) map.get(key);
}

public <T, S extends T> boolean contains(Class<T> key, Class<S> value) {
    List<Class> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) return false;
    return list.contains(value);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.add(Number.class, Integer.class); // compiles
    m.add(Number.class, String.class); // does not compile.
}
```

Comment: +1. Note however that m.add(Number.class, Number.class); also compiles.

Comment: You are right, `extends` doesn't have to be a strict sub-class in this context.

Comment: And how would you code the getters with this way of doing things ?

Comment: @Raveline, added some examples.

Comment: It gives you want indirectly, since I don't believe it can be done directly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
class MyMap<T extends Class<?>> extends HashMap<T, List<T>> {

}
```

Won't entirely solve your problem. You can see that on single entries in the map it cannot vary.