# Is it possible to avoid this unchecked cast?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm writing a simple event system for parameterized events, which uses a `Map` from classes to `Set`s of handlers which have that class as their parameter.  My understanding is that [I can't define that relationship between key and value types via parameter restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8184049/46387) and I'm getting unchecked cast warnings pulling elements out of the sets.

Here's what I have currently:

```
public class Manager {
    private class Event<T> {
        // getSubject(), etc.
    }

    private interface Handler<T> {
        public T handleEvent(Event<T> event, T subject);
    }

    private final Map<Class<?>, Set<Handler<?>>> handlers = new HashMap<Class<?>, Set<Handler<?>>>();

    public <T> void post(final Event<T> event, final T subject) {
        final Class<?> type = subject.getClass();

        if (this.handlers.containsKey(type)) {
            for (Handler<?> handler : this.handlers.get(type)) {
                // unchecked cast
                ((Handler<T>) handler).handleEvent(event, subject);
            }
        }
    }

    public <T> void register(final Class<T> type, final Handler<T> handler) {
        if (!this.handlers.containsKey(type)) {
            this.handlers.put(type, new HashSet<Handler<?>>());
        }

        this.handlers.get(type).add(handler);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid this unchecked cast?  Is there perhaps a flaw in my design?

I've spent quite some time here and on Google, but was unable to find anything which quite covered this arrangement.

Comment: Google Collections' [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) comes to mind but you need `ClassToInstance*Multi*Map`

Answer (score 1):

If the event classes themselves form a hierarchy, you can avoid casts by using a Visitor pattern. It's extremely cumbersome in Java, but there are no casts necessary.

Comment: There's only one `Event` class, which is parameterized according to what type of object it represents.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was if the possible subjects `T` formed a hierarchy.  That way you could use, e.g., `Event< BaseSubject >` instead of `Event< ? >` and make your event handlers into visitors.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The types being used as the parameter are external to the project and mostly inherit directly from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can do nothing more than `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in this situation.

There's nothing in your map declaration that keeps you from associating a `Class<A>` with a `Set<Handler<B>>`, so the compiler can't possibly know whether this is the case or not. And sadly, there's no way to impose such a constraint on any implementation of `java.util.Map`.

If you were to implement your own data structure that allows this enforcement (providing methods like `Handler<T> getHandler(Class<T> type)`, you would only end up burying the unchecked cast in that data structure and keep your client code clean.

As a side note, the `Map` interface expects an `Object` as a parameter for `get()`, `containsKey()` and alike, so all the generic stuff gets lost anyway (even if you could associate the generic type of the key with the one of its corresponding value, which is simply not possible).

Answer (score 0):

My code organization is a little different, [Code for Broadcasters, the equivalent of your Manager, here](https://www.assembla.com/code/hastur/subversion/nodes/58/Hastur_A22/src/com/flyingspaniel/event/Broadcasters.java) but in my code for post() I do the equivalent of

```
for (Handler<T> handler : this.handlers.get(type)) {
   do stuff ...
}
```

Since the event argument is parameterized by T, you can add the `<T>` to the Handler.  But I do a lot of the fancy Generics stuff by guessing and blundering, YMMV...  :-)

p.s. your register() method should be synchronized.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.  (Assuming that doing so is possible, anyway.)

Comment: Yes, I do have @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").  I don't think I ever figured out a way around that.  We are probably both stuck in the same place.  And we developed very similar code.